# How Can I Test Whether a Variable Contains an Element Value or a String / Number Value? (XSL 1.0)

Tags: variables, xslt, xslt-1.0

I would like to know how to test for whether a variable contains an element value or a simple string / number in XSL 1.0.

```
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="is the variable an element">
           <!-- do some stuff -->
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
           <!-- do some other stuff -->
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

### More Detail About My Problem

I have an XSL similar to the one below. Sometimes the variable may be an element and sometimes that element may have no value (i.e. nil = "true"). This is why I use the `$imAStringButICouldHaveBeenAnElementForAllYouKnow[normalize-space()]` test to check that the element has a value.

However, running this XSL with Saxon 6.5.5 fails with 'The value is not a node-set'. I can see why, the variable is indeed not a node set; I need an additional check before this one to confirm whether or not the variable contains an appropriate value.

**XSL**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:variable name="imAStringButICouldHaveBeenAnElementForAllYouKnow" select="'string'"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <!-- If this is an element I want to know does it have a value? -->
        <xsl:if test="$imAStringButICouldHaveBeenAnElementForAllYouKnow[normalize-space()]">
            <!-- do some stuff -->
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit what do you mean by element value and string number stating some examples

Comment: Sure. An element value is a kind of node that is a tag and looks like `<this>`. It must have a name and an associated end tag. I could assign the variable an element value by using a `select="someNodeName"` attribute in my variable declaration. A string or number value is  not associated with an element, just a stand alone value. They can be assigned to a variable by using a `select="'I'm a string'"` or `select="1"`.

Comment: so why cant you check for the first character as an opening bracket?

Comment: @Saksham Try it and see.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think this is possible with XSLT 1.0 (I would welcome being proven wrong). Any node-set function that would work on an element, will result in a fatal error if applied to a string.

How do you get to a position where you don't know in advance what's in your variable? It seems to me the real problem is there.

---

Note that you *can* check for the existence of a text value, regardless of the variable content's type by using:

```
<xsl:if test="normalize-space($myVar)">
```

This will return true when the variable is a non-empty, non-whitespace-only string OR an element that has a non-empty, non-whitespace-only descendant text node.

---

### Edit:

I haven't noticed you are using Saxon 6.5 (until Michael Kay pointed this out in his answer). In such case, you can take advantage of the EXSLT `exsl:node-type()` extension function which Saxon 6.5 supports, e.g.:

```
<xsl:if test="exsl:object-type($myVar)='string'">
    <!-- do something -->
</xsl:if>
```

or

```
<xsl:if test="exsl:object-type($myVar)='node-set'">
    <!-- do something -->
</xsl:if>
```

Comment: Thank you for your thorough answer @michael.hor257k, using `normalize-space($myVar)` was the ideal solution for me :) I'm interested to follow up on your suggestion that I should perhaps never find myself in a situation where I don't know what's in my variable, you could well be correct.

The problem arose from the fact that I am using a template that takes a variable that is intended to hold element values. But occasionally I want to 'massage' the data, so I perform a substring on the element value. I believe this dynamically takes the text() child of the element and casts it to a string?

Comment: I am not sure I follow. In XSLT, variables are immutable. If the stylesheet selects an element as the contents of the variable, then the variable's data type will **always** be `node-set`. Applying the substring() function on the variable will indeed return a string - but that string will not become the contents of the variable. OTOH, if the variable is defined to select a substring of the element's text value, then the variable's data type will **always** be `string`. -- P.S. The proper term for what you call "element value" is "element": http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#dt-element

Comment: Thanks for your clarification on the terminology. I may not have been clear, but what you said in your last sentence is close to what is happening, with the exception that I am not applying the substring to the element's text value, but instead to the element itself. In this case I believe the text() child of the element is dynamically selected and cast to a string.

Comment: @Scribe A string function cannot be applied to a node-set, so there's an implicit conversion taking place: `substring(myElement, 1)` is interpreted as `substring(string(myElement), 1)`.

Answer (score 1):

It can't be done in pure XSLT 1.0. If you are running Saxon 6.5.5 then it should be easy enough to switch to Saxon 9.5 and XSLT 2.0 which offers immense benefits, quite apart from the "instance of" operator which provides the solution to this problem.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Michael Kay, I would very much like to use XSLT 2.0 but unfortunately I am not in a position to change the XSLT engine we use right now. I'll consider it for the future :)

Comment: I wish you luck in finding a position where you have more influence on important decisions ;-)